# Guidance on sencha document

Tags: extjs

I am very new in the sencha doc. But anyone has any tips on reading the doc? As I found the methods to the certain Ext. Like Ext.panel.Panel can do this

```
var Panel1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: roomstore,
        selModel: checkbox,
        border: 0,
        id: 'Panel1'
//...
}
```

But it does not state the attributes like store, selModel, etc..I only manage to retrieve these attributes from other sources..any help? Thanks

Comment: The grid panel is inherited from panel panel. You are configuring a grid, but am looking at a panel in the docs.